# Create trigger to update different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new in creating triggers. Please help in creating an update trigger when I update my one table, it updates other two tables as well. I have three tables named tblDHColl, tblDHSurv and tblDHLithology. All the tables have some common fields like 'Dataset', 'HoleID' and 'Validated'. What I want is, when I update 'Validated' field in tblDHColl table with value "1", it should update 'Validated' fields with same value in other two tables. I have two values 1 (True) and 0 (False) to update this column. Please help me to create a trigger to update other two tables.

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056

Comment: As it stands this question cannot be answered.  At the very least, you need to provide the relevant parts of the table structures for the three tables.  We do not need to see all columns, the relevant ones will do.  But we need to know which columns uniquely identify the rows in the other two tables.  Also as it stands, the question assumes you only want to synchronize when validated is updated to 1.  What happens if it is changed to 0?  Or can it only ever go from 0 to 1? (In which case your trigger needs to prevent changes in the other direction).

Answer (score -1):

i have created a trigger on tblDHColl. So if you will update tblDHColl.Validated from 1 to 0 or 0 to 1 , the trigger will update the other 2 tables.

```
 create table tblDHColl ( HoleID int ,  Dataset int ,  Validated int)
 create table tblDHSurv ( HoleID int ,  Dataset int ,  Validated int)
 create table tblDHLithology ( HoleID int ,  Dataset int ,  Validated int)

 insert into tblDHColl 
 select 1,100, 1
 union all select 2,500, 0
 union all select 3,700, 1
 union all select 4,300, 0
 union all select 5,900, 1

  insert into tblDHSurv 
 select 1,100, 1
 union all select 2,500, 0
 union all select 3,700, 1
 union all select 4,300, 0
 union all select 5,900, 1


  insert into tblDHLithology 
 select 1,100, 1
 union all select 2,500, 0
 union all select 3,700, 1
 union all select 4,300, 0
 union all select 5,900, 1
 go


create trigger tr1 on tblDHColl
for update
as 
begin
    declare @Validated_new int , @Validated_old int , @HoleID int
    select @HoleID = i.HoleID ,@Validated_new=i.Validated from inserted i
    select @Validated_old=d.Validated from deleted d

    if (@Validated_new <>@Validated_old )
    begin 
        update tblDHSurv
        set Validated =  @Validated_new 
        where HoleID = @HoleID

        update tblDHLithology
        set Validated =   @Validated_new  
        where HoleID = @HoleID
    end 

end
go


update tblDHColl
set Validated = 1
where HoleID = 2

select * from  tblDHColl  where HoleID = 2
select * from tblDHSurv  where HoleID = 2
select * from  tblDHLithology  where HoleID = 2
```

Comment: This is not good. You should never move data from `deleted` and `inserted` to variables like this because both tables can contain multiple rows. Your trigger will not work correctly when you update more than 1 row at time. ie: `UPDATE tblDHColl SET Validated = 1 WHERE HoleID in (1,2,3)`  - you update 3 rows, but trigger will activate only for one.

Comment: yes , i know.  however there is no data structure or background provided in question. so i wrote a simplest trigger to give some idea. Above trigger will also file if  HoleID is not a PK. And if you think no one should never do that , than why SQL server allowing it? so when to use variable and when to use Inserted & deleted tables in join completely depend on you requirement.